# PydanticV2 Discriminating between N types

Tags: python, pydantic

Given the following JSON file:

```
{
  "foo": {
      "x": {
         "someField": 0
      }
  }
}
```

Where foo.x can be one of different N objects, i.e: the following is also valid:

```
{
  "foo": {
      "y": {
         "someDifferentField": "0",
      }
  }
}
```

But the following is not:

```
{
  "foo": {
      "y": {
         "someDifferentField": "0",
      },

      "x": {
         "someField": 0,
      }
  }
}
```

(i.e. JSON file can only have foo.x or foo.Y not both)

I am loading JSON of the forms above into Pydanatic model that looks like this:

```
class SomeObject(BaseModel):
   pass

class X(SomeObject):
   someField: int
    
class Y(SomeObject):
   someDifferentField: str


class Foo(BaseModel):
    """TODO."""
    aObject: Annotated[
        Union[X, Y],
        Field(validation_alias=AliasChoices("X", "Y")),
    ]
```

This works for de-serialization but does not work for serialization, as calling `foo.model_dump()` will get:

```
{
  "foo": {
      "aObject": {
         "someDifferentField": "0",
      },
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "foo": {
      "aObject": {
         "someField": 0
      }
  }
}
```

Note: aObject is printed instead of 'X' or 'Y'

How do I fix this?

Note: Cannot change the schema of the json files.

Answer (score 0):

Discriminated union with callable discriminator is what you need.

```
from typing import Annotated, Any, TypeAlias, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, Discriminator, Tag, TypeAdapter, ValidationError

class SomeObject(BaseModel):
    pass

class X(SomeObject):
    someField: int

class Y(SomeObject):
    someDifferentField: str

class FooX(BaseModel):
    x: X

class FooY(BaseModel):
    y: Y

def get_discriminator_value(v: Any) -> str:
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        x_y = v.get("x", v.get("y"))
        if x_y:
            if x_y.get("someField") is not None:
                return X
            elif x_y.get("someDifferentField") is not None:
                return Y
    return None

Foo: TypeAlias = Union[Annotated[FooX, Tag(X)], Annotated[FooY, Tag(Y)]]

foo_adapter: TypeAdapter[Foo] = TypeAdapter(
    Annotated[Foo, Discriminator(get_discriminator_value)]
)

data_y = '{"y": {"someDifferentField": "0"} }'
y = foo_adapter.validate_json(data_y)

data_x = '{"x": {"someField": "0"} }'
x = foo_adapter.validate_json(data_x)

print(y.model_dump())
print(x.model_dump())
```

Output:

```
{'y': {'someDifferentField': '0'}}
{'x': {'someField': 0}}
```

https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/unions/#discriminated-unions-with-callable-discriminator

Comment: Attempted: 

    aObject: Annotated[
        Union[
            Annotated[X, Tag("X")],
            Annotated[Y, Tag("Y")],
        ],
        Discriminator(get_discriminator_value),
    ]

But getting 

Field required [type=missing, ...

Comment: I added the example to my answer

Comment: I see that's not what you wanted to get. I'll try to fix it

Comment: Updated. Hope it's what you need