# How to make the model based on other field's value in pydantic

Tags: python, json, pydantic, pydantic-v2

I have two different models and they are based on a field in basemodel. The problem is that the field is not a dictionary or object, it is just a string. That's why [discriminated-unions](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/unions/#discriminated-unions). And I tried to use field_validator and RootModel but none of those helped me.

Here is the examples of a json file:

```
{
   "model": "model_a",
   "some_value": "value_a"
}
```

```
{
   "model": "model_b",
   "another_value": "value_b"
}
```

Here is the models:

```
class ModelA(BaseModel):
      some_value: str

class ModelB(BaseModel):
      another_value: str

class Model(BaseModel):
      model: Annotated[Union[ModelA,ModelB], Field(discriminator="model")]
```

Those models not working the reason is that input should be a valid dictionary or instance of object not a string

Answer (score 0):

In your code example you need to add `model` field to each model:

```
class ModelA(BaseModel):
    model: Literal["model_a"]
    some_value: str

class ModelB(BaseModel):
    model: Literal["model_b"]
    another_value: str

class Model(BaseModel):
      model: Annotated[Union[ModelA,ModelB], Field(discriminator="model")]
```

Comment: Hi @yurii-motov. Not really I think you have missed that model is not an object for those fields in my example. This one will work in your code:
 `"model": { "model": "model_b", "another_value": "value_b"}}`
but I don't want to have 'model' as an object to those fields.

Comment: I have found a solution that I can use your model and update the json by adding model as a root ;) thanks for helping

Comment: Yes, I missed that.. You can do that without additional field by using descriminated union with callable, like it's shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77956923/pydanticv2-discriminating-between-n-types#77957235